# 買う、買い取りする、買い取る what is the difference?

Tags: grammar, words

I'm a bit lost on all the ways to say "to buy". Can anyone help me understand the difference? According to my research it seems that 買い取りする and 買い取る are used when the shop buys something for the customer, like a notion of trade, but I'm not sure of that and I don't understand the difference between the する version and the non-する one. If you can give me some examples to understand it, it would be nice :)
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

買い取る probably emphasizes that you make the item yours, e.g. 別荘を買取る.

On the other hand, for 買取 (or 買い取りする),  it can refer to companies buying used goods from you. For example, if you have an unneeded computer, you may want to search "パソコン 買取".

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! It's much more clear. Just one last clarification : what's the nuance in term of meaning between 別荘を買い取る and 別荘を買取する ?